# Good trying v.s. Good try; No touch v.s. No touching

Tags: grammar

A kid tried to open a water bottle but he failed. What would the teacher say? Good trying or good try, which one is correct?

A kid was walking in the hall; he touched the wall while walking. What would the teacher say? No touching or no touch?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You need to show some research. Also, your question is better suited to the English Language Learner site. https://english.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

"Good try" because his attempt, his *try* (noun) was good (determined, effortful, technical, etc.)

As for the second example, the teaching is referring to the act of doing something, i.e., the [gerund](https://www.google.com/search?q=gerund&rlz=1C1GCEA_enUS873US873&oq=gerund&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i59j0l3j69i60l3.669j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) form of the verb *to touch*. No touch*ing*.

Note that this is an negative imperative, and not a declarative parallel of your "try" example. A more direct parallel, e.g., "good [nice] touch" does exist, and would be used for example in cases such as:

> "Thanks for reviewing my document, you gave it some nice touches."